# Joomla website does not display properly in IE compatibility mode

Tags: joomla-3.4

I am using Joomla 3.4.5 with protostar template, Image Show GK4, Vinaora Nivo Slider

In Internet Explorer (IE) 11, the website works fine, but lot of users have compatibility mode turned on, which makes IE think the website is designed for older versions of IE and the website does not load properly. I realize using a responsive template means it scales down elements using CSS3 media queries which are not supported on older browsers.

I cannot ask users to turn off compatibility mode or use another browser like Chrome.

The index.php has , but it does not fix the issue.

What can be done to address this?

Comment: Why don't you simply use Javascript to detect if the user has compatibility mode enabled and if so, display a message recommending they disable it. I really don't see why you should cater for people who have compatibility mode enabled.

Comment: Thanks, lot of my audience is of age 45+ and may not know how to disable compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding the following `meta` right after the opening `<head>`element of the template and see how IE in compatibility will load the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

This will tell IE in compatibility mode, to try to load the page with its latest mode.

As side note, the compatibility mode is not meant to be used by default. It's there so users can switch to it when have to view a webpage built for older IE.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This did it. I appreciate your assistance and time.